# Обращение к значениям всех словарей которые находятся в модели C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, словари, data-structures

Хочу попытаться достучаться до значений словарей, которые обернуты в модель данных, но в итоге получаю не то что нужно. Необходимо получить данные со всех словарей сразу методом GetAll();
Модель данных:

```
public class Model
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> FirstDepartment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> SecondDepartment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> ThirdtDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

Менеджер или репозиторий

```
public class Manager
{
    private Model _model;
    private List<Model> _lst;

    public Manager()
    {
        _lst = new List<Model>();

        _model = new Model()
        {
            FirstDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>(),
            SecondDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>(),
            ThirdtDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        };

        _model.FirstDepartment.Add(1, "Вася");
        _model.FirstDepartment.Add(2, "Петя");
        _model.SecondDepartment.Add(3, "Катя");
        _model.SecondDepartment.Add(4, "Иван");
        _lst.Add(_model);
    }

    public List<Model> GetAll() => _lst;

}
```

Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=======================================");

    Manager mg = new Manager();

    foreach (var item in mg.GetAll())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"++++ {item} ++++");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне упаковать правильно, а потом перебрать все значения всей модели (Values всех словарей).

Comment: в чем смысл добавлять единственную модель, которая и так есть как поле, в список и возвращать список с одной моделью внутри и пробовать эту бедную модель сконвертировать в строку?

Comment: Получается просто сделать стринговые поля и уже в менеджере добавлять в структуру данных?

Comment: запостил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конкатенация значений словарей:

```
public class Model
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> FirstDepartment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> SecondDepartment { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> ThirdtDepartment { get; set; }
}

public class Manager
{
    private Model _model;

    public Manager()
    {
        _model = new Model()
        {
            FirstDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>(),
            SecondDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>(),
            ThirdtDepartment = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        };

        _model.FirstDepartment.Add(1, "Вася");
        _model.FirstDepartment.Add(2, "Петя");
        _model.SecondDepartment.Add(3, "Катя");
        _model.SecondDepartment.Add(4, "Иван");     
    }

    public List<string> GetAll() => _model.FirstDepartment.Values
                                        .Concat(_model.SecondDepartment.Values)
                                        .Concat(_model.ThirdtDepartment.Values)
                                        .ToList();

}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine("=======================================");

Manager mg = new Manager();

foreach (var item in mg.GetAll())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"++++ {item} ++++");
}

Console.WriteLine();
```

Вывод

```
=======================================
++++ Вася ++++
++++ Петя ++++
++++ Катя ++++
++++ Иван ++++
```

Comment: Оййй, спасибо!!!!! Огромное!

Comment: @JDo на здоровье :)